# Error:(24, 11) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8.0.+

Tags: android, sdk

Pleas help with this error cause it's my first android project !
Gradle Sync: 
pply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.interceptor.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8.0.+'

}
```

On Gradle console i get:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8.0.+.
  >    Versions that do not match:
  >        24.0.0-alpha1
  >        23.2.1
  >        23.2.0
  >        23.1.1
  >        23.1.0
  >        + 14 more
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
  >        file:/D:/Users/INTERCEPTOR/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  >        file:/D:/Users/INTERCEPTOR/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  >        file:/D:/Users/INTERCEPTOR/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
  >    Required by:
  >        MyApplication:app:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the correct version for the `appcompat-v7` dependency.

The **latest** stable version of the above-mentioned dependency to now is:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Use it as above and make sure you installed/updated to the latest version in **SDK Manager** before.

Comment: compile version was established by default when i started the project! I'm trying to make an android app for android 2.2 + if it matters... But still thanks for solution!

Comment: Can't install 23.2.1. Studio package manager says it is downloaded, but Gradle says `Failed to resolve`

Comment: @konopko it could be helpful if you inform us about the error more than just `Failed to resolve`

Comment: @SHiON Gradle message: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1. Package manager says it is installed, but I can't find it in SDK directory.

Comment: @konopko use standalone SDK Manager and clear its cache from Tools>Options, then reload it. Delete and reinstall android support library.

Comment: Gradle sucks. Projects wich compiles suddenly stopp Building for no apparent reason. Maven is so much more reliable.