# Unable to find dependency com.android.support support-v4 23.1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am Working with unity 5.3.4f1. I need to use google play service repo:37. This google play service use android m2repository and google m2repository. I have both installed from SDK manager still I am getting below error.

```
ERROR: Unable to find dependency com.android.support support-v4 23.1+ 
in     ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:FindCandidate(Dependency)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:LoadDependencies(Boolean, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String,     OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

How Can I solve this error.

[image: extra/android/]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the correct version for the `appcompat-v7` dependency. You can check this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/522).

> The **latest** stable version of the above-mentioned dependency to now
>   is:
>
> ```
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
> ```
>
> Use it as above and make sure you installed/updated to the latest
>   version in **SDK Manager** before.

You might also check the workaround on these links:

- [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235542/5832311)

  > 1. in Android Studio, open Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
  > 2. under tab "SDK Tools" un-check the libraries causing problems
  > 3. click "apply" to uninstall them
  > 4. re-check the same libraries
  > 5. click "apply" to reinstall them
  > 6. close SDK Manager and run Gradle sync / build
- [Error:(24, 11) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8.0.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960303/error24-11-failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v78-0)
- [Build failed even after downloading Google repository](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/issues/10)